# Finicky error with http get in Ionic (3.19.0)

Tags: typescript, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Problem:**

I am using Ionic's http get function, and I often get the following error:

```
Typescript Error
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.
```

The line supposedly causing the error looks a bit like the following:

```
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-api/', {}, {headers: headers})
```

According to [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#get) my usage should be correct, no?

EDIT: 
I just tried copy/pasting Ionic's example get() usage into my project and am getting the same error.

[image]

---

**Some Fixes:**

I have found the following sometimes fixes this specific error:

- Make random changes to my project, save, rerun 'ionic serve'
- Ensure my CORS plugin on my web browser is on
- Ensure there aren't other errors in my project (mis-aligned {}'s, etc)

---

**Question:**

The non-deterministic fixes are somewhat troubling so I thought I'd ask if anyone knows if one thing in an Ionic project could cause the above behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there were some mismatched imports.  I originally had:

import { Http } from '@angular/http';

But I needed:

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';